Forwarding of zigbee coordinator received frames to a beagle board
I was wondering how I would go about forwarding the frames received by the zigbee coordinator to a beaglebone black.  I have connected the rx and tx of the coordinator to the UART4 rx and tx of the beagle board but something is not working.  Could anyone give me any pointers?
I tried probing the other pins on the zigbee but I still don't see frames in the beagle board.
